# Can't get LetsEncrypt SSL certificate to work with AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, lets-encrypt, amazon-lightsail

I'm setting up a domain with AWS Lightsail but I cat gete it to work on HTTPS. I followed the instructions here: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/
Also tried this: https://cloudconfusing.com/2018/05/13/moving-a-lightsail-instance-to-https-with-lets-encrypt-certbot/

```
    bitnami@ip-172-26-9-58:/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
Unmonitored apache
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80
Monitored apache
bitnami@ip-172-26-9-58:/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt$ ls -la /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/
total 312
drwxr-xr-x  5 bitnami root   4096 Dec 10 12:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root    root   4096 Aug 15 10:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 bitnami root   4096 Dec  7 15:39 bitnami
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root    289 Aug 15 10:43 deflate.conf
drwxr-xr-x  2 bitnami root   4096 Aug 15 10:40 extra
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root  20149 Aug 15 10:46 httpd.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root  13077 Jul 30 15:17 magic
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root  60847 Jul 30 15:17 mime.types
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root   7413 Aug  2  2012 modsecurity.conf
drwxr-xr-x  3 bitnami root   4096 Aug 15 10:40 original
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root  17447 Aug 15 10:43 pagespeed.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root 141034 Aug 15 10:40 pagespeed_libraries.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root    199 Aug 15 10:41 php-fpm-apache.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root   1834 Dec  7 15:39 privkey.pem
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root     59 Dec 10 12:19 server.crt -> /etc/letsencrypt/live/previdencia-digital.com/fullchain.pem
-rw-------  1 root    root   1164 Dec  7 15:39 server.crt.old
-rw-------  1 root    root    985 Dec  7 15:39 server.csr.old
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root     57 Dec 10 12:19 server.key -> /etc/letsencrypt/live/previdencia-digital.com/privkey.pem
-rw-------  1 root    root   1679 Dec  7 15:39 server.key.old
-rw-r--r--  1 bitnami root    203 Aug 15 10:42 ssi.conf
```

I also tried creating the certificate inside Lightsail console, by going on Load balancer -> Create a certificate -> filling the data -> Create
But simply nothing happens. No error message or anything.

I thought port 443 was blocked in the firewall, but it is open just like port 80 in the instance networking settings. Any ideas on what else I could try?

Comment: here is the error I'm getting on Lightsail console: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uNFcMzf4ZWM-XxDefmKwsD7yNc__DcxY/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to adjust the permissions on the key and the cert. Try this:

`sudo chmod 600 /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*`

Notice how the permissions on your new key/crt don't match those on your old ones.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that was it. I deleted and re-created the instances, and it just worked. Must have been permissions. Thanks!

(Just to be clear, it worked with LetsEncrypt)

Answer (score 2):

i did it successfully with my lightsail application and it is working fine.i did the following steps.

1. Turn off all Bitnami services: sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
2. Request a new certificate for your domain (**replace your email and domain**) :sudo lego --tls --email="EMAIL-ADDRESS" --domains="DOMAIN" --domains="www.DOMAIN" --path="/etc/lego" run [ You can use more than one domain (for example, DOMAIN and

   www.DOMAIN) by specifying the --domains option as many times as the
   number of domains you want to specify ]
3. Bitnami has already a default key and crt file please rename those :

   mv/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt.old

   mv/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key.old

   mv/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.csr/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.csr.old
4. Create a symbolic link : Replace DOMAIN with your domain
   ln -s /etc/lego/certificates/DOMAIN.key /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key
   ln -s /etc/lego/certificates/DOMAIN.crt /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt
5. Change permissions
   chown root:root /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*
   chmod 600 /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*
6. restart your service:
   /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start